# Proper way to include a js library file in a directive, avoiding relative path that may change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a project which is not using any method for including angular code other then loading them directly into our html page (and won't get permission to include any tool for awhile from my manager).

Currently if I want to use a provided javascript/angular/bootstrap element I would simply include it in my index.html, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/angular/angular-file.js"/>
```

I am now writing a directive.  In the html template I want to use an already written third party angular directive to provide a tree view.  I thus would want to include this script within my directives html template to insure it's loaded, rather then trusting this to the index.html has already loaded the script.

However, I don't want to use a relative path, or at least am afraid doing so will cause my directive to break later.  the html template for my directive is buried under a tree structure, something like " portal/modules/simulation/templates/whatever"  I don't want to have to place "../../../../../lib" in the template because it's ugly, but also because there is a chance that we may move the angular files around and I don't wan that to break my directive.

Is there a cleaner way of including the library without making a presumption about multuple layers of file structure, some way to work relative to the 'top layer' of my file structure etc?

is it considered clean for my directive to have it's *own* lib directory that contains the third party angular directive, rather then being part of shared lib directory?  For that mater I believe that the third party tree view directive I'm using is dependent on other angular and jquery code, so I don't know if I may accidentally be dependent on something in the top level index.html file loading some angular/jquery code my directive uses without realizing it.  Am I over worrying about making my directive stand alone when I shouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I pack up templates using grunt and [grunt-angular-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates). If you use something like this, you can reference your template as `myModule/fileNameOfTemplate`, and since the template is already in memory (using the `$templateCache`) you don't make any extra requests and the code doesn't care at all about the path to the actual file.

Without adding extra modules, build steps, etc...

foo.js

```
var fooModule = angular.module('foo', []);
fooModule.run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("foo/mytemplate.hmtl", "Really" +
                     "really" +
                     "long" +
                     "string");
}])
fooModule.directive('bar', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'foo/mytemplate.html'
    }
});
```

Now it doesn't matter where you store the module - you're just pulling the file out of the template cache.

Alternatively, templateUrl can accept a function - you could write a function to determine the path of the module or something.. but that's going to be super brittle.

Comment: I completely agree that grunt would solve the issue.  unfortunately I can't use grunt, my manager considers configuring it 'refactoring' and says we don't have time for it.  I...disagree but it's not my decision.

Comment: Well, this just makes templates neat and tidy. I'll edit with a 'more to the core' idea.

Comment: @dsollen You have to do this on server side. Considering that you have a variable with 'portal/modules/simulation/templates/whatever' path, you should apply it to index file on either build time (Grunt) or run time (PHP, Express w/view templates, whatever). Since you haven't specified the details on server side setup, the answer is the best option.